# how to add back button in navigation bar in sencha touch?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In `Innerdata.js`, i have a `a` tag and on tap event i navigate it to the `Group.js`.

`Gruop.js` contain some html.I try to add here navigation bar with back button. Here the only Navigation bar is display no back button. Now this is where I fall down, I can't figure out why the Back button is not display.

I am trying to add Back button in navigation bar in `Group.js` page so when i click this button i navigate to the `Inner.js` page.so what is the problem  here?

`Inner.js:`

```
Ext.define('chat.view.Inner', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'Inner',
    config: {
        items: [
            {xtype:'Innerdata'}
        ]
    }
});
```

`Innerdata.js:`

```
Ext.define('chat.view.Innerdata',{
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'Innerdata',
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                html:'<a class="groupimg"><img src="stylesheets/images/groupchat.png"/></a>',
                listeners: [
                {
                    element: 'element',
                    delegate: 'a.groupimg',
                    event: 'tap',
                    fn: function() {
                        console.log('One!');
                        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('chat.view.Group'));
                    }
                }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
});
```

`Group.js:`

```
Ext.define('chat.view.Group', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    //extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'Group',

    config:{
        items: [
                {html:'<div>Hello Hello Hello Hello</div>'}
                    ]
    },
    onBackButtonTap:function(){
        this.callParent(arguments); 
    }

});
```

here is the screen shot of `Group.js` page, i am trying to add Back button in Blue bar.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a misuse of `Ext.navigation.View` in your code. Please don't use it in your situation.

Here are some explanations and instructions on how you can fix this problem:

- If a view, says `Group.js`, is a subclass of `Ext.navigation.View`, it works according to push/pop pattern. Please see an example here: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View. That's why a navigatioin view, which you applied to `Group.js`, should never have a back button on the top and very first screen.
- So, there's no reason to use navigationview in this case. You just need to use a simple `Ext.Container` instead. So change your parent class of `Group.js` to `Ext.Container`. After that, add a toolbar on the top, add the back button to it and bind a handler.

> ```
> Ext.define('chat.view.Group', {
>   //extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
>   extend: 'Ext.Container',
>   xtype:'Group',
>
>   config:{
>      items: [
>         {xtype: 'toolbar', 
>         docked: 'top', 
>         items: [
>           {xtype: 'button', 
>           text: 'Back',
>           ui: 'back',
>           handler: function(){Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('chat.view.Inner'));}}
>         ]}
>         {html:'<div>Hello Hello Hello Hello</div>'}
>      ]
>   },
>
> });
> ```